# Image4io and NodeJS: Documentation is clearly outdated. How do I upload an image?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I guess this is as much a call to attention on the fact that the documentation seems to be outright incorrect in its application, as well as just generally lacking. Normally, I would send that part of the message to them personally, but, their contact form is also giving me errors and not sending, so it's not like I have the means to anyway. In the mean time, I'm more worried about getting this code to work, so hopefully someone experienced with this SDK or an Image4io team member sees this and can provide a public answer for others stumbling into this road block.

For starters, I initialized the Image4io object as described in the github here: https://github.com/Image4IO/image4ionodeSDK/

website documentation: https://image4.io/en/documentation/api-sdk/#operation/UploadImage

The image upload example provided on the website's documentation looks like this:

```
let client=new Image4ioAPI.Image4ioAPI(apiKey,apiSecret);
var request = new Models.UploadImagesRequest("/folderName", true, true);
request.Add("/path/to/image/location/name-of-the-image.jpg", "name-of-the-image", "name-of-the-image.jpg");
let response=client.UploadImage(request);
```

3 out of the very sparse 4 lines of code they provide give errors. Where did this Models object come from? There is no corresponding class in the import and the code example obviously doesn't show where it was defined. Just what is it and where did it come from?

Well, I found a matching function "UploadImagesRequest" in the original import class, so my guess is Models was deprecated and its functionality was moved into the Image4io class object. If that was the case the solution would be to simply access that function instead... But it's not used the same. It has 4 arguments, the 4th being a "Image4io.UploadFile[]" type. This type has no use examples in the documentation or further details describing what it is *exactly*. I assume image byte data goes in there somehow, but how?

Finally we have request.Add... except we don't because that isn't a function :( it looks like this was used to actually get the image data (maybe of the type UploadFile?) based on the path of the image. If this function is gone now, how do get file data for use in the upload request function?

Any and all help in figuring out this SDK would be greatly appreciated. Google searches yielded no meaningful results, so hopefully we can help in that department as well. For all I know I just got the wrong version somehow. I guess I could try downgrading to a version that matches the documentation but... that's not a fix in my eyes at all.

Let me know if there's any more info I could provide to help

Answer (score 1):

You can upload image like this:

```
var client=new Image4ioClient(API_KEY,API_SECRET);
var files=Array();
files.push(new UploadFile("./test.jpg","test.jpg"));

client.UploadImage(new UploadImagesRequest("/",true,false,files))
    .then(res=>console.log(res))
```

If you have binary data at hand, you can write it to a temporary file and then upload them.